# A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, flutter-inappwebview

MY AGP is 8.1.4 and flutter version is 3.16.5
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

=> What went wrong:
**A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview'.
**> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.

> Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

```
 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.
```

I want add package inappwebView to my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What does this mean?

In newer versions of the Android Gradle Plugin and Gradle, the `namespace` was shifted from the `AndroidManifest.xml` to `app/build.gradle`. Generally, this means the following:

In all three AndroidManifest.xml files (main, debug, profile), remove the `package` attribute:

```
<!-- This is how it should look like: -->

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->
</manifest>
```

In `app/build.gradle`, add this line:

```
android {
    namespace "com.example.yourpackage"
    ...
}
```

However, this requires **all** modules in your project to add the `namespace`. It seems like your [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) does not have this attribute yet.

### How to fix this error?

1. Define the namespace globally as descibed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76364984/19960585) SO answer
2. (**recommended**) Downgrade Gradle and wait for your packages to migrate to newer versions

Comment: the new version from flutter inappwibView solved the problem the main problem I have it that I'm using package is named flutter_paypal_payment that have old version from flutter inapp webview but I could solve the problem Thank you