call_log: ^4.0.0 package not working in new flutter version

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':call_log'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/77814682/10423080

The package call_log seems to be discontinued...
Try this one which seems to do the same: https://pub.dev/packages/call_e_log
You can also fork yourself the original package and fix namespace problems according to A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_inappwebview'
Before adding a new package to your project, you need to evaluate if it not going to be discontinued.
